# Counting the frequency of a list of XML values

Tags: python, list, frequency, counting

I have the following code that I'm using in Python to get a count of the unique userids from a discussion list:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('Combined.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for node in tree.findall('.//discussions/discussion/userid'):
    print (node.text)


print (len(tree.getroot().findall('.//discussions/discussion/userid'))) 
unique_list = [] 


for x in tree.getroot().findall('.//discussions/discussion/userid'): 
        if x not in tree.getroot().findall('.//discussions/discussion/userid'): 
            unique_list.append(x) 
for x in unique_list: 
        print ("The unique list is: ", x, end="")
```

I receive the following as my output:

...
16055
16055
16059
1760
22519
16055
21961
16790
13764
13779
13764
18601
18398
16790
25092
154

Is there any way that I can count the frequency of occurrence of the unique values from this list?  (for instance, 16055 : 2, 16059: 1, etc...)

Any help would be greatly appreciated...Bob

Answer (score 0):

To generate a counter, you could generate a dictionary and increase its counter:

```
count_dict = {}

for x in tree.getroot().findall('.//discussions/discussion/userid'):
        if x not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(x)
            count_dict[x] = 1
        else:
            count_dict[x] = count_dict[x] + 1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input.  When I run this code, I get <Element 'userid' at 0x0000027DBC633C28> and not the userids along with their counts

Answer (score 0):

A `Counter` would work well here:

```py
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(tree.getroot().findall('.//discussions/discussion/userid'))
```

The reason being that `Counter` is based off of `dict`, which has unique keys

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python dictionary for the purpose:

```
id_count = {}
for u in unique_list:
    if u in id_count:
        id_count[u] += 1
    else:
        id_count[u] = 1
```